# Javascript RegExp, word boundaries and accents

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

Word boundaries are not taken in account if the letter near the word boundary is accentuated:

```
"aé ae".match(new RegExp("é\\b", 'igu')); // null
"aé ae".match(new RegExp("e\\b", 'igu')); // ["e"]
```

How could I make it work?
Three requirements:

- I need to use the RegExp constructor (as the word to match is variable)
- It's not envisageable to replace all accents
- The solution needs to work on both sides: `\bword\b`

Comment: Not an answer, but you might check out the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com) library, which is rather more complete and flexible than JavaScript's built-in RegExp.